# Hausdorff distance between rows of 2 column

Tags: python, pandas

Given a data frame:

```
df = 

    car     lat    lon
0   0   22.0397 3.6531
1   1   22.0367 3.5095
2   2   22.0713 3.5346
3   3   22.1249 3.5922
```

I have calculated the euclidean distance to get matrix:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform, pdist

pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(df.iloc[:, 1:])), columns=df1.car.unique(), index=df1.car.unique())
```

Now I want to get [Hausdorff Distance](https://github.com/mavillan/py-hausdorff) and get the matrix.

---

I tried:

```
def hausdorff(p, q):
    p = p #Need to choose row
    q = q #Need to choose row
    return hausdorff_distance(p, q, distance="euclidean")

distance_df = squareform(pdist(df1.values, hausdorff))
euclidean = pd.DataFrame(distance_df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to choose rows, this does [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) for you. It calls the user-supplied function for all row combinations. So just supply the row vectors to `hausdorff`. The only caveat is that [`hausdorff_distance`](https://github.com/mavillan/py-hausdorff/blob/848c76f21614ced7d3afffbf39b4a2ec0553e569/hausdorff/hausdorff.py#L39) expects two 2-dimensional arrays as input, so you need to reshape them.

```
def hausdorff(p, q):
    p = p.reshape(-1,2)
    q = q.reshape(-1,2)
    return hausdorff_distance(p, q, distance="euclidean")

pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(df.iloc[:, 1:], hausdorff)), columns=df.car.unique(), index=df.car.unique())
```

Result:

```
          0         1         2         3
0  0.000000  0.143631  0.122641  0.104728
1  0.143631  0.000000  0.042745  0.120907
2  0.122641  0.042745  0.000000  0.078681
3  0.104728  0.120907  0.078681  0.000000
```

---

The above just answers the technical question of how to use a user-defined function with `pdist`. Depending on what you're trying to achieve I guess you'll need to supply arrays with more than just one row, e.g. all rows for a given car as in the following example:

```
import itertools as it

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'car': [0,0,1,1,2,2], 'lat': 22+pd.np.random.rand(6), 'lon': 3+pd.np.random.rand(6)})
#   car        lat       lon
#0    0  22.426797  3.006383
#1    0  22.894152  3.558360
#2    1  22.657756  3.969983
#3    1  22.788719  3.969007
#4    2  22.025103  3.854048
#5    2  22.867389  3.760920

cars = df1.car.unique()
p = []
for c in it.combinations(cars, 2):
    p.append(hausdorff_distance( df1.loc[df1.car==c[0],['lat','lon']].to_numpy(), df1.loc[df1.car==c[1],['lat','lon']].to_numpy()))
pd.DataFrame(squareform(p), columns=cars, index=cars)
```

Result:

```
          0         1         2
0  0.000000  0.990892  0.917975
1  0.990892  0.000000  0.643188
2  0.917975  0.643188  0.000000
```

Please note however that the Hausdorff distance is a directed distance, i.e. h(x,y) != h(y,x). `hausdorff_distance` computes the maximum of h(x,y) and h(y,x), so you can't populate the distance matrix from it. You can use [`directed_hausdorff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.directed_hausdorff.html) for correctly creating the distance matrix.

Comment: Stef, is your answer with `itertools ` with itertools is acceptable for number of cars more than 2?

Comment: The 2 in `it.combinations(cars, 2)` means be create pairs of two elements and these pairs are then passed to the distance calculation. You can't change it to 3 or any other number as the distance is always between 2 points.

Comment: ok. thanks! It was additional question actually. The thing is, in my real data I have different number of long lat couples, as my every car recorded different number of times

Comment: the number of entries per car in the dataframe can be any number, this has nothing to do with the number 2 in `it.combinations(cars, 2)` (sorry if my first comment wasn't very clear about this)